# How do I count total record of database in pagination of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Normally, I tried like the following

```
$user = User::all();
```

and I just `count($user)` But when I have to paginate like the following

```
User::paginate(10);
```

How do I get total record of user?

> I don't want to query `User::all()` again.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can access it with `total()` helper method.

```
$users = User::paginate(10);
$users->total();
```

Note that this is not available when using `simplePaginate`. See the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination) for further information.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is why I love Laravel.